# Any way to setTypeFace from url for a Textview?

Tags: java, android, android-typeface

I want to setTypeFace from url like : https://github.com/anak10thn/frontend-homepage/raw/master/font/helvetica-regular.otf

Do you know if there any way ?

I tried this :

```
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromFile("https://github.com/anak10thn/frontend-homepage/raw/master/font/helvetica-regular.otf");

            tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

It doesn't work.

I have this error :

```
03-24 04:46:59.931    1314-1314/bya.fchps.buildyourapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: bya.fchps.buildyourapp, PID: 1314
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bya.fchps.buildyourapp/com.fchps.buildyourapp.views.ClassicView}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made
        at android.graphics.Typeface.<init>(Typeface.java:175)
        at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromFile(Typeface.java:159)
        at com.fchps.buildyourapp.views.ClassicView.setClassicLabel(ClassicView.java:178)
        at         com.fchps.buildyourapp.views.ClassicView.onCreate(ClassicView.java:75)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at            android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Comment: Hi instead of directly set the URL in to the Typeface, I would suggest first download the otf file in your device, then give the local otf file path to Typeface.I think this would better to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can not directly add the URL of font in Typeface. If you want to dynamically use the font in your application, the best option is application would download fist font in local device. Then define the path of font in to the Typeface.

```
Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromFile(
    new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "font.ttf"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe you can actually. The custom typeface is usually kept as a system resource file, and not referred to as a web document. As far as i know, the best method would most likely be: Create a fonts folder in your assets folder. Download the font you desire and place it in the fonts folder, and then in the code refer back to your fonts folder. For further detailed instructions refer to this website: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm